# How to set Ripple effect on a LinearLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, background, android-linearlayout, clickable

I want to set the background `android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground` to a `LinearLayout`. When using XML there are no problems (it works)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llMiner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true" >
```

... but I have to do this in java code, so I've tried this

```
llMiner.setClickable(true);
llMiner.setBackgroundResource(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground);
```

... and it doesn't work, infact I get a `NotFoundException` on this second line.
So after I've tried this variant thinking that the resource is a Color.

```
llMiner.setClickable(true);
llMiner.setBackgroundColor(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground);
```

This one doesn't launch exception, but... doesn't work (there are no changing of background when pressing, but the state change in pressed as it have to do)... any suggestion?

Comment: are you changing the color in onClick method of your activity..???

Comment: Then i think you must override onClick method to get your functionality done.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and no success so far. If you found a solution please let me know, or if someone knows if this can actually be done, give feedback. Thx!

Comment: For anyone looking for the support lib's counterpart, it is `android.support.design.R.attr.selectableItemBackground`.

Comment: My previous comment doesn't seem to work now (or maybe it never did). What works now is `R.attr.selectableItemBackground`.

Comment: @Splact Please choose my answer if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can use this way.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, then we can use the Theme's
    // selectableItemBackground to ensure that the View has a pressed state
    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
    textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
}
```

Comment: Not working for me, white color, they don't arrive to keep the colorAccent from theme on pre lollipop device

Comment: If you want to keep your theme colors use R.attr.selectableItemBackground instead of android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground

Comment: Using `R.attr.selectableItemBackground` will use the AppCompat's attribute (if you are including that) and falls back to fade in/out instead of ripple for pre Lollipop, by default. Note that `R` is your `packagename.R`.

Comment: Upvote for the working answer, it really helps, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this helpful extenstion

```
fun Context.makeCircleRippleDrawable(
    @ColorInt rippleColor: Int = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black_alpha_25),
    @ColorInt backgroundColor: Int = ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent),
    @ColorInt disabledColor: Int = backgroundColor,
    elevation: Float = 0F
): Drawable {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        val content: GradientDrawable?
        val mask: GradientDrawable?

        if (backgroundColor == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
            content = null
            mask = GradientDrawable()
            mask.setColor(rippleColor)
            mask.shape = GradientDrawable.OVAL
        } else {
            content = GradientDrawable().also {
                it.shape = GradientDrawable.OVAL
                it.color = ColorStateList(
                    arrayOf(
                        intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_activated),
                        intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_enabled),
                        intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_enabled)
                    ),
                    intArrayOf(
                        backgroundColor,
                        backgroundColor,
                        disabledColor
                    )
                )
            }
            mask = null
        }

        RippleDrawable(
            ColorStateList(
                arrayOf(
                    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed),
                    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_focused),
                    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_activated)
                ),
                intArrayOf(
                    rippleColor,
                    rippleColor,
                    rippleColor
                )
            ),
            content,
            mask
        )
    } else {

        val shapePressed = GradientDrawable()
        shapePressed.shape = GradientDrawable.OVAL
        shapePressed.setColor(rippleColor)

        val shapeDefault = GradientDrawable().also {
            it.shape = GradientDrawable.OVAL
            it.color = ColorStateList(
                arrayOf(
                    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_activated),
                    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_enabled),
                    intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_enabled)
                ),
                intArrayOf(
                    backgroundColor,
                    backgroundColor,
                    disabledColor
                )
            )
        }

        val stateListDrawable = StateListDrawable()
        stateListDrawable.addState(
            intArrayOf(
                android.R.attr.state_pressed,
                android.R.attr.state_enabled
            ), shapePressed
        )
        stateListDrawable.addState(intArrayOf(), shapeDefault)
        stateListDrawable
    }
}
```