# How do I add selectableItemBackground to an ImageButton programmatically?

Tags: android, attr, r.java-file

android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground exists, but how do I add it programatically to an ImageButton?

Also, how would I go about finding the answer in the documentation? It's mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html), but I don't see any explanation of how it's actually used. Actually, I rarely seem to find the documentation useful, but I'm hoping that's my fault and not that of the documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398610/how-to-get-the-attr-reference-in-code

Comment: Please note mine is a two part question, the second not being adressed in the other thread.

Answer (score 54):

Here is an example using answer here: [How to get the attr reference in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398610/how-to-get-the-attr-reference-in-code)

```
    // Create an array of the attributes we want to resolve
    // using values from a theme
    // android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground requires API LEVEL 11
    int[] attrs = new int[] { android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground /* index 0 */};

    // Obtain the styled attributes. 'themedContext' is a context with a
    // theme, typically the current Activity (i.e. 'this')
    TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);

    // Now get the value of the 'listItemBackground' attribute that was
    // set in the theme used in 'themedContext'. The parameter is the index
    // of the attribute in the 'attrs' array. The returned Drawable
    // is what you are after
    Drawable drawableFromTheme = ta.getDrawable(0 /* index */);

    // Finally free resources used by TypedArray
    ta.recycle();

    // setBackground(Drawable) requires API LEVEL 16, 
    // otherwise you have to use deprecated setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) method. 
    imageButton.setBackground(drawableFromTheme);
    // imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableFromTheme);
```

Comment: This did not work, at least on Lollipop with AppCompat. However, [this did.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28087443/1489860)

Comment: Code works fine for me on Lollipop with AppCompat (May 2017) - only difference was I used `View.setForeground(Drawable)` instead of `setBackground()`

Answer (score 51):

If you are using AppCompat you could use following code:

```
int[] attrs = new int[]{R.attr.selectableItemBackground};
TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
int backgroundResource = typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0);
view.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource);
typedArray.recycle();
```

Comment: @Renges you should set flags `setClickable(true)` and `setFocusable(true)`

Comment: setFocusable(true) is unnecessary here and actually excessive as long as item could get into the sate of 'focused item' and got gray background. The ripple effect will work even without this attribute set

Comment: Focusable is for accessibility, it should be on clickable items

Comment: what about foreground? there is no method like setForegroundResource

Answer (score 9):

This works for me with my `TextView`:

```
// Get selectable background
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, typedValue, true);

clickableTextView.setClickable(true);
clickableTextView.setBackgroundResource(typedValue.resourceId);
```

Because I use AppCompat library, I use `R.attr.selectableItemBackground` not `android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground`.

I think `typedValue.resourceId` holds all drawables from `selectableItemBackground` than using `TypeArray#getResourceId(index, defValue)` or `TypeArray#getDrawable(index)` which are retrieve only a drawable at the given `index`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this method:

```
public Drawable getDrawableFromAttrRes(int attrRes, Context context) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {attrRes});
    try {
        return a.getDrawable(0);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

// Then just call it like this:

```
getDrawableFromAttrRes(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, context)

// Example
ViewCompat.setBackground(view,getDrawableFromAttrRes(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, context))
```

Comment: Sometimes Android Studio will warn about using `R.attr.selectableItemBackground`, so it may be safer to replace it with `android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground`