# Image "inside" button while keeping standard animations

Tags: android, xml, button, imagebutton

I would like to define a button in Android, through XML, which, below the standard Button graphics (change color when clicked, slightly rounded edges,...), shows an image of my choice. I would like the final product to be somewhat like this:

[image]

I have tried change the `src` and `background` of an ImageButton, but it does not provide the intended effect. Could you please point me some way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that's not exactly what you mean by **standard**, but when you set a background, you end up having to recreate the behavior when the button is clicked. The best way to do it in Android is by using a `selector` as your button's background. Create a XML drawable with the `selector` in it.

Example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_default" />
</selector>
```

That way, when your button is clicked, it will change the background to other image that does what you want.

**EDIT:**

1. There are other modifiers such as `focused`, if you need.
2. If you want Lollipop's ripple effects, I think you can create a `Layout` and put your button inside it. Change the `Layout` background and set the button background to transparent. If that doesn't work, try adding `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to your button.

Answer (score 0):

As Paulo said, you can achieve the click effect with a selector. 
See this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30192562) it gives the code for a very nice and customizable ripple effect.