# Making entire cardview clickable

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a recycler view of cardviews, where each cardview contains a textview and a listview. I want the entire cardview to be one clickable item. Currently, if I click on the textview portion of the cardview it works, but clicking on the list portion does nothing. The listview appears to be stealing focus from the parent cardview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android-L CardView Visual Touch Feedback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475150/android-l-cardview-visual-touch-feedback)

Comment: I have already included what the answer there suggests. The cardview I have is clickable, just that the listview seems to be stealing focus and making that portion of cardview not clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought if more elegant solutions could not be found: you may try overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent()` for the `cardview` and use a [gesture detector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) which listens for a tap up on the motion event intercepted. Return `true` if the gesture is detected, such that the MotionEvent is intercepted and not passed on to its children, including the listview.

This way the `cardview` could see the click event before the `listview`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to define following attribute in your cardview. I'm not sure it will work, I do not know why in some cases it solved the problem for me, on others not...

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```