# How do I create a dynamically-generated CardView List?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am wondering how we can create CardView Lists (dynamically generated cardview items). I'm surprised I can't find any info on how to create CardView lists on the developer.android.com site. I can usually find whatever I'm looking for.

I have seen quite a lot of stuff online but from what I've seen, its still using generic views, not CardViews. How can we create a list with cardviews?

Comment: You want to create a list with many different CardView items in it, or a CardView with a list inside it?

Comment: Urm... @Benjamin, a list with many different CardView items in it

Comment: Just to add, when I implemented a ListView of clickable CardViews, this answer was helpful for getting the selector states working on all api levels, it's a little tricky since on pre-api 21 the elevation is "fake": http://stackoverflow.com/a/30192562/4409409

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'll check that out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering how we can create CardView Lists (dynamically generated cardview items)

Use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. Use `CardView` as the root layout for your row layouts, wrapping around whatever the "real" stuff is in the row. And you're done.

`RecyclerView` will be the more common choice, simply because it was released at the same time as `CardView`. Many of [my `RecyclerView` samples](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView) use `CardView`, such as [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/CardViewList) and [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/CardRippleList3).

> I'm surprised I can't find any info on how to create CardView lists on the developer.android.com site

That's because there is nothing much different about creating a list containing `CardView` widgets than there is about creating a list containing any other sort of widget. `CardView` is just a subclass of `FrameLayout` with a nice drop shadow effect. It is not rocket science, nor is it brain surgery.

Comment: Thanks @Commoms. I'm still really new to Android dev. Finding it a bit difficult coming from the .net world