# Ripple Effect on androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am trying to add ripple effect on click of card view strangely it is not coming up?

What could be wrong here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="6dp"
    app:ignore="NamespaceTypo"> 


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

// I have a linear layout with three textview inside the cardview.

RecyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/cardList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use any `background/foreground` in `CardView`. If you use any background color then, then just add `app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardBackgroundColor`. Remove any `padding` from the `CardView`. Use `margin` for space between items.

**Now, for the ripple effect in `CardView`, just add an immediate child layout in your `CardView`.** Set `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` in the child layout. Add any necessary `padding/margin` in the child if you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="6dp"
    app:ignore="NamespaceTypo"> 

        <!-- Child Layout -->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Your content here -->
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: If I do this I don't get space between each item and I don't see the ripple effect too

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. You can use `margin` in CardView for space between items. Check the updates.

Comment: I really don't get why this is the solution ... yes it works, but feels like a hack. 1. system should automatically add ripple effect when clickable is defined, 2. ripple effect is defined by colorOnSurface https://material.io/components/cards/android#card 3. other mentions say set foreground .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475150 which is the same bad hacky solution to me .. does anybody really UNDERSTAND why this is the solution and can explain it in manner of the material design and theme system?

Comment: @childno͡.de ripples are a special kind of `Drawable` (`RippleDrawable`) that draw an effect when you touch them. They can either draw onto the bounds of their `View`, or they can be "borderless" which means they need to draw on the background of a View they're "inside" in the hierarchy. This empty layout just has a bounded ripple drawable for its background - `CardView`s have their own special background drawable (giving it the card edges) so you can't just swap that for a ripple drawable in XML. But if you set a click listener on the `CardView` it should add a ripple itself automatically

Answer (score 2):

Existing CardView does not having ripple effect, use MaterialCardView it has ripple effect.

here is the sample code for MaterialCardView

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/myCard"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

<!-- Your child layout -->

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` in favor of `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` that will give that function out of the box.

Background: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/cardview is the new base superseding https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#v7-cardview and Material Components https://developer.android.com/reference#other-libraries are build on top of androidx.cardview using foreground and rippleColor as defined per https://material.io/components/cards/android#card anatomy ... so check out if you customize your `?attr/colorSurface`, `?attr/colorOnSurface` or `app:cardForegroundColor` to set matching values each other for a visible change

But: sounds like there are new issues with that like https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1095 ‍♂️
and the code documentation seems to be a bit weired anyway https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/card/MaterialCardView.java#L303