# Touch feedback with RecyclerView and CardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, rippledrawable, touch-feedback

I would love to enable touch feedback for my Open-Source library.

I've created a `RecyclerView` and a `CardView`. The `CardView` contains different areas with different `onClick` actions. Now I would love to trigger the Ripple effect if a user clicks anywhere in the card, but I'm not able to achieve this behavior.

This is my listitem,
You can find it on GitHub too: https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries/blob/master/library/src/main/res/layout/listitem_opensource.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_rect_normal"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/libraryName"
            android:textColor="@color/title_openSource"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeLarge_openSource"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/libraryCreator"
            android:textColor="@color/text_openSource"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeSmall_openSource"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/dividerLight_openSource"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/libraryDescription"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeSmall_openSource"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="@color/text_openSource"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="20">
    </TextView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/libraryBottomDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/dividerLight_openSource"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/libraryBottomContainer"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/libraryVersion"
            android:textColor="@color/text_openSource"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeSmall_openSource"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/libraryLicense"
            android:textColor="@color/text_openSource"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeSmall_openSource"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the `onClick` is set on 3 parts of this layout. `libraryCreator`, `libraryDescription`, and `libraryBottomContainer`.

I hope someone got an idea what is going wrong here.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was now able to solve the issue.

The problem is that i use onClickListener on the TextViews and this click listener prevents the RippleForeground from being notified about the touch event. So the solution is to implement an TouchListener on those TextViews and pass through the touch event.

The class is really simple, and can be used everywhere:

```
package com.mikepenz.aboutlibraries.util;

import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by mikepenz on 16.04.15.
 */
public class RippleForegroundListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    CardView cardView;

    public RippleForegroundListener setCardView(CardView cardView) {
        this.cardView = cardView;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Convert to card view coordinates. Assumes the host view is
        // a direct child and the card view is not scrollable.
        float x = event.getX() + v.getLeft();
        float y = event.getY() + v.getTop();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            // Simulate motion on the card view.
            cardView.drawableHotspotChanged(x, y);
        }

        // Simulate pressed state on the card view.
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                cardView.setPressed(true);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                cardView.setPressed(false);
                break;
        }

        // Pass all events through to the host view.
        return false;
    }
}
```

It can be used by adding this as TouchListener:

```
RippleForegroundListener rippleForegroundListener = new RippleForegroundListener();
older.libraryCreator.setOnTouchListener(rippleForegroundListener);
```

This listener will just pass through the touch event to the CardView and trigger the correct Ripple effect. (You can also modify this to take any view. It should not be limited to a CardView)

Comment: what is `older.libraryCreator.setOnTouchListener(rippleForegroundListener);` ?

Comment: @MohitKhaitan the view which should pass the Touch to the RippleView. There's also an updated version of this, without keeping the context. https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/aboutlibraries/util/RippleForegroundListener.java
Used here: https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries/blob/61fea18a81ee593e3ece62ca884cf296b25428a5/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/aboutlibraries/ui/adapter/LibsRecyclerViewAdapter.java#L229

Comment: I upvote this because unlike other answers it correctly pointed the reason why my LinearLayout (in my case I used LinearLayout instead of CardView) did not get the selection effect. But your solution does not seem so easy. Is this the way Google intended? Can't this be achieved in the layout XML file alone?

Comment: I created UntouchableTextView by subclassing TextView, and overrode onTouchEvent and returned false. The method body is just "return false" but the boilerplate code (especially the constructors) is kind of annoying. Now I replaced TextView with UntouchableTextView in the layout XML file, the LinearLayout gets the touch event. I wish TextView had a simple attribute like android:hitTest="false" so this could be done in one line...

Comment: now I finally know what was the problem, but your solution has one problem: swipe event is also recognized as click and click effect works out

Answer (score 123):

Assuming you are using Material/Appcompat theme and Lollipop,I got this to work by making the CardView have the following attributes:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: no this didn't work :/. Still no click feedback. Just on the areas without an onClick listener

Comment: @Gak2, I think you need to set `android:background` instead of `android:foreground`. Setting this made it work for me.

Comment: using foreground did nothing for me. If there is something to what you suggest, then please explain further.

Comment: I'm going to guess that your problems are because android:foreground only works for FrameLayouts or classes that inherit FrameLayout like CardView. If you try to set it in a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout, it won't work

Comment: As @AvinashR said, setting  android:background works. However, a better enhancement would be this: 

`android:clickable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" `

This way, the background uses the default touch selector on pre Lollipop devices and a beautiful ripple on Lollipop and above :-)

Comment: Changing to `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` will use fade effect on pre-Lollipop and ripple on Lollipop and above.

Comment: Certainly  you get a nice feedback  if you surly add the theme : android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
to your root element

Answer (score 52):

CardLayout is just a subclass of ViewGroup, So setting:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

should do the trick.

**UPDATE:**

*(looks like you are trying to use a custom ripple color.)*

Try using a ripple drawable with custom color as the background (I haven't used this, So I cannot verify this behavior.) see: the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049148/list-view-set-a-custom-ripple-selector) to get you started.

Comment: How I set it programmatically?

Comment: I found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531516/how-do-i-add-selectableitembackground-to-an-imagebutton-programatically

Comment: I got this working by also setting `android:focusable="true"` and `android:clickable="true"`.

Answer (score 22):

for me:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

made it finally work.
see background of recyclerView / content behind the item, and also see the ripple effect used with recyclerView.

Answer (score 14):

None of the above answers worked for me or was either too complicated.

Then I realized I had to set the following properties in THE RECYCLERVIEW ADAPTER LAYOUT.

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

Then I got it to work.

Comment: that needs a min of API level to be 11

Comment: @war_Hero Is this a problem really?

Comment: In a way yes, since recyclerview is intended to work till version 7

Comment: On the bright side most of the newer apps support jellybean and above so your answer also works

Comment: Technically, It's not the case. I was able to fix my problem just by looking for a clue in your snippet. The real issue is you should not be using `android:clickable="true"` uncesseriliy everywhere. It should only be in CardView. Then it works.

Answer (score 9):

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

If you use foreground instead background, you don't need to use clickable or focusable

Comment: Tried all the other answers, this one works perfectly for me by just adding it to the `CardView`!

Comment: Works perfectly with differently colored cards too. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, i was need to show custom background and ripple effect as well. So the way I achieved this is by applying these two attributes on the root layout of my recycler-view item:

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_bg"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem as Jiang:

**I have to set the attributes to the layout-file, which is inflating the RecycleView.**

My Main-Layout: (**Don't** add the properties here!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My RecycleViewAdapter:

```
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_center_item, parent, false);
```

My list_center_item.xml (**Add the properties here!**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"


android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add following lines in the layout that you are using under `CardView`

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="@drawable/my_ripple"
```

Example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="@drawable/my_ripple">
```

Comment: And what is the drawable file for `@drawable/my_ripple`?

Answer (score 0):

**The actual silly issue was in my case is the following....**

Technically, It's not the case just like everyone suggests here in my case. The real issue is you should not be using android:clickable="true" uncesseriliy everywhere in the `LayoutView`, `RelativeView` or `TextView`.

**It should only be in CardView.** **Then it works like charm**

`android:focusable="true"` Is not really requied.

Just add the following in your CardView

`android:clickable="true"
 android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/card_template_item_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/card_size_height"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/card_template_item_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/card_template_item_image"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/card_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/card_title_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/card_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/card_title_size"
                android:text="@string/place_holder_item_name"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/card_template_item_sub_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/card_template_item_title"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/card_sub_title_padding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/card_sub_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/card_sub_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/card_sub_title_size"
                android:text="@string/place_holder_item_category"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```