# RecyclerView + CardView + Touch feedback

Tags: android, touch, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Has anybody solved the mystery of the **CardView** without touch feedback when it's inside a **RecyclerView**?

I have a RecyclerView with a bunch of CardViews (a **CardList**). When I click on any CardView, I start another Activity. That's working pretty fine, but I can't see any touch feedback when I click on the CardView.

Just in time, I've already configured my CardView (XML) with these:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android-L CardView Visual Touch Feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475150/android-l-cardview-visual-touch-feedback)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Background:**

The `CardView` ignores `android:background` in favor of `app:cardBackground` which can only be color. The border and shadow are in fact part of the background so you cannot set your own.

**Solution:**

Make the layout inside the `CardView` clickable instead of the card itself. You already wrote both attributes needed for this layout:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: Hey! Sorry! You were right. What was cheating me is that I'm using the Theme.Material theme, and it's a "dark" theme. Since I've changed to Theme.Material.Light, and used your answer, the touch feedback took place.

Comment: This works okay in Lollipop and above. On Kit Kat the background of the inner view does not cover the whole cardView (here is where you realize the shadows are fake in Kit Kat). It's okay but not perfect. I can live with it for now.

Comment: Yes, I think I had the same problem. I don't remember how I solved it but setting `contentPadding` on the card to the same value as negative `cardCornerRadius` (to be precise the root value of it i think) should do half the job (make sure to set `useCompatPadding` to `true`). The second half is creating a custom background `<shape>` STATEFUL! drawable with the same corner size. The third half is defining a drawable-v21 which uses ripples  instead. I'll try to update the answer with a sample later.

Comment: `android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"` on `CardView` was a cleaner solution for me since making the layout inside `CardView` clickable was disabling my the item click listener

Answer (score 8):

#### Solution 1

As @Eugen proposed, you can make the layout inside `CardView` clickable, so then you can use `android:background`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
```

#### Solution 2

If you don't want to lose the item click listener by making the layout inside `CardView` clickable, you can use `android:foreground`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
```

---

**Extra**: you can use `"?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` instead of `"?attr/selectableItemBackground"` if you don't want the rectangle mask.

Comment: foreground for the CardView is the only solution that worked with me. Thank you.

Comment: This code sample is confusing - there's no layout in the CardView. What's the point of borderless selector if it's already clipped by the card shape? It looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

create selector "drawable/card_foreground_selector"

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#18000000"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/card_radius" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#0f000000"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/card_radius" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and create "drawable/card_foreground.xml" (***you'll need to tweak inset values according to elevation of your card***)

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:drawable="@drawable/card_foreground_selector"
android:insetLeft="2dp"
android:insetRight="2dp"
android:insetTop="3dp"
android:insetBottom="3dp"/>
```

modify your item (item.xml)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:contentPadding="8dp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/card_foreground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    // ..

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

you can view original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30192562/5192139)

Comment: Instead of creating a new drawable I just used `android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: @CarloRodríguez That's "?selectableItemBackground" for AppCompat. Does it work on all platforms? The custom drawable is used before Lollipop because the corners on ?selectableItemBackground aren't clipped.

Comment: @EugenPechanec you're right, I didn't realize the corners aren't clipped before Lollipop, it may be still a good option if card view has no corner radius.

Answer (score 1):

Add `foreground` attribute:

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Approach should work the same way.

***1)***  If you want cardview to respond to touch feedback then use this one in **cardview**.

```
 android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
```

---

but if above approach is not working then you can set this property on ***child*** view group (Linear/Relative etc) of **cardview**.

```
   android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
```

But then `itemView` of ViewHolder will not respond to the ***touch*** event. since its been ***consumed*** by child view so you have to **set** **clicklistener** on childview to work on further with listener in recyclerview adapter, this way we can enable touch as well as click events on row items of recyclerview in our adapter.

if you have hard time following the touch and click on views in cardview with ripple then this might be helpful. [Touch Feedback Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29858443)

***2.)*** The second approach is to use the traditional way of using custom touch selector drawable and set as background.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="your ripple color">
    <item>
    <selector>
        <item android:state_selected="true">
            <color android:color="your selected color" />
        </item>
        <item android:state_activated="true">
            <color android:color="your selected color" />
        </item>
        <item>
            <color android:color="your normal color" />
        </item>
    </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Docs [Ripple Drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html)