# CardView containing a frame layout is not clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

Following is my xml layout.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/contentMain"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom|end"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottomMargin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/customProgress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/smallPlayer_home"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/selected_track_image_sp_home"
                        android:layout_width="54dp"
                        android:layout_height="54dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/myvisualizerview"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/album1"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                        app:civ_border_width="0dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/selected_track_title_sp_home"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/player_control"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="13dp"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/player_control_sp_home"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_animatable"
                            android:visibility="visible"/>
                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/bufferingIndicatorMain"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:visibility="invisible"
                            app:indicator="BallSpinFadeLoader"
                            app:indicator_color="#FFFFFF"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Im using the following code to set On click listener for the cardview,

```
bottomCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showFragment("streaming");
            }
        });
```

The problem is that the cardview click event is not getting fired.
I have also tried setting onFocusChangedListener upon cardview but still the onClick event is not getting fired.

How can I be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

You should set click listener for layout inside your cardview that is frame layout.You can try putting clickable property too like this 
          android:clickable = "true"

Also can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760974/recyclerview-cardview-touch-feedback) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475150/android-l-cardview-visual-touch-feedback)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [Shalini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39264718/421467) or,
set `clickable` and `focusable` to `false` for inner layout (in your case `bottomMargin` FrameLayout), and set `clickable` and `focusable` to `true` for the CardView, as you already did.