# Android: Generic clickable view with visual feedback

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to implement a generic method which makes `View`-objects clickable. This is my current implementation:

```
public static <V extends View> V clickable(V view, OnClickListener listener) {
    view.setFocusable(true);
    view.setClickable(true);
    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view.setOnClickListener(listener);
    return view;
}
```

It works. The problem now is to add visual feedback for the user. I would like to somehow visualize the focus and the click.

An example would be the section titles in *Google Play Store*. The section titles look like normal text with a fake button, but when touching them, the whole background (text and fake-button) changes.

I know about the solution with xml-files, where I have to specify `<selector>` and `<item android:state_pressed="true">` and so on.

But how to implement the focus/click visualization in my generic method?

Comment: I would check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20539545/105771

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a background drawable to the view which has selectors defined in it using:

setBackground
setBackgroundResource

you may have to qualify the call based on the platform if you are supporting older phones.

Comment: Isn't there already a generic "background drawable" defined in android default theme which I could use? For example that one, which is used by ListView...