# Make a ViewGroup have the default clickable animation in Android

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, viewgroup, android-viewgroup

I have a `ViewGroup` (specifically a `LinearLayout`) which I would like to be clickable, and have the normal click actions/animations (for example, the background color changes just a bit when clicked (pre-Lollipop) and have the ripple animation (Lollipop).

I have an onClickListener setup, and have set clickEnabled to true, but still I get no animation.

How can I get this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` as your background to support the default click animation.

You can use it in xml like this:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: @sandy try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531516/how-do-i-add-selectableitembackground-to-an-imagebutton-programatically