# Transparent background in ImageButton with ripple effect?

Tags: java, android, xml, imagebutton

I want to **programmatically** remove the grey background in ImageButton. I tried many method of removing it like -

```
imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

but on implementing them, I don't get the ripple effect on the ImageButton on touch. (No highlighting on touch).

Is there any way to remove the background but preserve the ripple effect or highlight.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set background highlight to a LinearLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732662/how-to-set-background-highlight-to-a-linearlayout)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` this works than I believe this answer should solve your problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28087443/2534007

Comment: Or even better, ```android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"```

Comment: This will crash on some devices.

Answer (score 13):

Create your own `RippleDrawable` and you need to use mask for the Ripple if you're going to use transparent background.

```
 <!-- A red ripple masked against an opaque rectangle. -->
 <ripple android:color="#ffff0000">
   <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
         android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
 </ripple>
```

Comment: `<ripple> requires API level 21 (current min is 17)` all the good stuff is obviously going to be useful in a few years when users have upgraded...

Answer (score 0):

To have a transparent background with ripple effect, the background Drawable needs to be a rippleDrawable, which can be transparent. Set it up programmatically like this.

```
var mask = new android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable();
mask.setShape(android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
mask.setColor(0xFF000000); // the color is irrelevant here, only the alpha
mask.setCornerRadius(5); // you can have a rounded corner for the effect

var rippleColorLst = android.content.res.ColorStateList.valueOf(
    android.graphics.Color.argb(255,50,150,255) // set the color of the ripple effect
);

// aaaand
var ripple = new android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable(rippleColorLst,null,mask);
yourImageButton.setBackground(ripple);
```

(Sorry for the JavaScript/NativeScript code, hope everyone can understand it)