# Ripple effect on a ImageButton does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I set an ImageButton in a RelativeLayout and i want to show a Ripple effect when the button get clicked. As far as i know it have to be enabled by default but for some reason it doesn't show even if i set `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` or `?attr/selectableItemBackground` as foreground or background (i used `?android:attr` instead of `?attr` too).

I tried everything, i made a custom Ripple effect drawable and setted it as foreground/background and it stills not working.

The app is API 21 > targeting 31, i don't know if it have anything to do with it but i using Material3.dark as main theme.

Anyone have an idea of what could be wrong here?

### ImageButon:

```xml
 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/tb_music"
            style="@style/top_bar_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/note" />
```

### Style top_bar_button:

```xml
<style name="top_bar_button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">64dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
        <item name="android:foreground">@drawable/ripple_effect</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    </style>
```

### ripple_effect.xml:

```xml
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#FFFFFF">

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"> </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

[How the button looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf60I.png)

Answer (score 0):

don't use `background` attribute with `ImageButton` or `Button`. These widgets have [9-patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch) set as background, so when you overwrite it you basically lose default Androids button style and padding. Now you bascially may have in here `ImageView` or even `TextView` with `drawable` set to left/right

for coloring button (image or common, or even other `View`s) use [`android:tint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#attr_android:tint) attribute, but this will work with API23+ (so you may look for some [compat/androidX version](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatImageButton) if you need API21, note it `implements TintableBackgroundView`, so we may assume that `tint` attribute will work, with custom not-`android` prefix)

also in question you should show your ripple effect drawable file, but even assuming that is is properly written - you have set transparent background, thus ripple effect won't be visible, as it works only in bounds of background - you transparent color removed default "shape" of this `View`. Just like `elevation` and `translationZ` params, these are adding some shadow under `View`, but only for not transparent, you've also lost this visual effect in here

so in short: remove `background` attribute leaving default one (or set it as non-transparent-at-all 6-hash solid color, but this will become just colored rectangle) and get familiar with `tint` and `tintMode`

aaand if you need a ripple effect on transparent rectange `View` then afaik thats possible also, but with [`mask`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364534/transparent-background-in-imagebutton-with-ripple-effect) param in `drawable`s XML. and you don't need `ImageButton`, any `View` is `clickable` in Android, especially when set `View.OnClickListener` using Java/Kotlin. so `ImageView` will be sufficiet

Comment: Sorry i forgot ripple_effect.xml. Just added.
So, basically is better use ImageView instead of ImageButton to make a transparent button with a icon and a nice ripple effect ?

Comment: buttons have own style and thats all. if you are removing this "default look" with e.g. solid background or other styling then there is no purpose for using `ImageButton` instead of `ImageView`. note that [`ImageButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton) `extends ImageView`, its almost same widget

Comment: Anyways i tried using ImageView instead and stills not showing up.

Comment: have you removed `background`, optionally adding `tint`? do you have AndroidX imported and current? update your current code

Comment: also note that [`android:foreground`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52329249/why-doesnt-androidforeground-attribute-work) attribute was made for `FrameLayout` initially and works for other `View`s since API23, so on some device/emulator with 5.0 API21 it won't work also (so use AndroidX for backward compatibility widget)

Comment: I testing it on a API 29 device

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why ripple does not work in your app but when I tested it, It is working properly. I think you didn't give padding to your `ImageButton`. You can see my XML code that how my code shows the Ripple effect.

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/note"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        <!--            Make sure that you have added padding to show ripple effect. Otherwise ripple effect not show-->
```

Let me know if your problem is not solved yet.

Comment: note that for using custom `app:srcCompat` you still need [AppCompatImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatImageButton), so importing AndroidX. when done IDE is probably automatically switching default `ImageButton`s to its `AppCompat` versions

Comment: @snachmsm I have imported AndroidX

Comment: Gonna try adding padding