# How to add borderless buttons programatically in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want the `onClick()` animation to be there on the buttons.

I have already tried

```
myButton.setBackgroundResource(0)
```

and

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

but both of these disable the `onClick()` animation.

Comment: what exactly your looking for ? any effect to your button on click, something like hower effect ?

Comment: Please elaborates what you want to do....the animation should on button or after clicking the button...

Comment: I am looking for the standard UI animation that happens when you click a button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a drawable with `<selector>` if you need to have control over your clickable item design.

If you only need to make your view transparent and apply system default pressed color, you can use AppCompat's `selectableItemBackground` as following:

```
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
myButton.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
```

or in XML:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732662/how-to-set-background-hilight-to-a-llinearlayout) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

You can create selector in drawable and can set as a button background.Here you can specify its stats pressed,focused etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:state_pressed="true" >
         <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
             <corners android:radius="3dip" />
             <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/theme_text_color" />
             <gradient  android:angle="-90"  android:startColor="@color/blue_transparent" android:endColor="@color/blue_transparent"  />            
         </shape>
     </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
         <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
             <corners android:radius="3dip" />
             <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/theme_text_color" />
             <solid  android:color="@color/theme_text_color"/>       
         </shape>
     </item>  
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >

             <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#00000000" />
             <gradient  android:angle="-90"  android:startColor="#00000000" android:endColor="#00000000" />            
         </shape>
     </item>
</selector>
```

In xml file

```
android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
```

or programatically

```
myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_button);
```