# GridView not react for onClickListener

Tags: android, xml, gridview

going with googleDevelopers example i create gridView with buttons, Everythink working, but when i create TOAST to show me the clicked position im no get any message. Can u guys look at code, maybe i do something wrong

Here is a xml file:

```
 <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pick_currency"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
```

Here i configuring the gridView in activity, of course i call this method in onCreate:

```
 private void configureGridViewCurrencySelect() {
        gridViewCurrency.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this));
        gridViewCurrency.setNumColumns(4);

        gridViewCurrency.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "klick " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is my ButtonAdapter:

```
 public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ButtonAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button buttonView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            buttonView = new Button(mContext);
            buttonView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 160));
            buttonView.setPadding(8, 20, 8, 8);
        } else {
            buttonView = (Button) convertView;
        }

        buttonView.setText(mThumbIds[position]);
        return buttonView;
    }

    private String[] mThumbIds = {"EUR/USD", "EUR/USD", "EUR/USD", "EUR/USD",
            "EUR/USD", "EUR/USD", "EUR/USD", "EUR/USD",};
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with disabling Button click ? is it working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using clickable(Button) item as row item in GridView Adapter, that is the reason your are not getting onItemClick called.

set your button clickable false and then try for the GridView onItemClick

This is common issue for ListView and GridView, if you have used any clickable control as a row item then your onItemClick will not be performed.

**OR**

Apply below attribute in your root layout in which GridView/ListView declared in layout xml

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Also apply below to your clickable control in row xml if any

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

**OR**

In your case you are adding button programatically into GridView adapter so, button is covering the whole area of a cell of GridView and because of this you will not have your problem resolved by above two solutions, you need to update your code as shown below.

Create new layout xml for GridView row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is you activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private GridView gridViewCurrency;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridViewCurrency = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        configureGridViewCurrencySelect();
    }

    private void configureGridViewCurrencySelect() {
        gridViewCurrency.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this));

        gridViewCurrency.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "klick " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ButtonAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Holder holder = null;


            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new Holder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_button, null);
                holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.button.setText(mThumbIds[position]);
            return convertView;
        }

        public class Holder {
            private Button button;

        }

        private String[] mThumbIds = {"EUR/USD", "EUR/USD", "EUR/USD", "EUR/USD",
                "EUR/USD", "EUR/USD", "EUR/USD", "EUR/USD",};
    }
}
```

This is your layout xml having GridView declared

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/activity_currency_select"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pick_currency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Pick Currency"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="40dp"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pick_currency"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You mean android:clickable="false"  ?

Comment: Add this line right after initialising new Button object in your adapter :

buttonView.setClickable(false);

Comment: buttonView = new Button(context);
            buttonView.setClickable(false);

i do this and now my button didnt react for click, i mean no ripple efect

Comment: Try this and remove clickable false line from  your code

button.setFocusable(false);
button.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

Comment: Now check my updated answer...

you can achieve this by applying this property to GridView also :  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135040/discussion-between-rikin-prajapati-and-rodriquez).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only remove this attribute from your `GridView`:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

and (even if it's not necessary, only if you want a single choice behavior) add this:

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having ClickListener on gridView, you can remove `android:clickable="true"` on GridView and apply `OnClickListener` directly in your adapter.

```
if (convertView == null) {
     buttonView = new Button(mContext);
     buttonView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 160));
     buttonView.setPadding(8, 20, 8, 8);
     buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Toast.makeText(mContext, "klick " + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      });)
} else {
    buttonView = (Button) convertView;
}
```

To get the ripple effect, you need to set the background of the button with `R.attr.selectableItemBackground`. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732662/how-to-set-ripple-effect-on-a-linearlayout-programmatically/28087443#28087443)