# Using listview and gridview in 1 activity, the gridview won't response on the item click

Tags: android, listview, gridview

Im trying to make activity that has listview of carts item on leftside, then listview of Categories on the center side, then gridview of Products on the rightside, which i want to do like this:
1. clicking item on category listview will filter products on the gridview
2. clicking item on product gridview will do another function, like save into tables and show it on listview on the left side

somehow i can't make the onclick working, its not error, but nothing happened onclick. why is that? if i only use 1 listview, its working. is it purely my code wrong or we cannot put multiple gridview/listview in 1 activity?
**onclick snippet:**

```
/* LIST BILL */
        final ArrayList<Bill> list_bill = getListBill();
        final ListView listview_bill = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.order_listing);
        listview_bill.setAdapter(new BillListAdapter(this, list_bill));

        listview_bill.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Bill mBill = list_bill.get(position);
                int bill_id = mBill.getID();

                Log.d(TAG, "click bill ID:"+bill_id);
            }
        });

private ArrayList getListBill()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("posDb",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        Cursor resultSet = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM bills",null);

        ArrayList<Bill> results = new ArrayList<Bill>();

        if (resultSet.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Bill billsData = new Bill();
                billsData.setID(resultSet.getInt(0));
                billsData.set_bill_no(resultSet.getString(1));
                billsData.set_type(resultSet.getString(2));
                billsData.set_table(resultSet.getString(3));
                billsData.set_qty(resultSet.getInt(4));
                billsData.set_amount(resultSet.getString(5));
                billsData.set_status(resultSet.getString(6));

                //put them into results
                results.add(billsData);
            } while (resultSet.moveToNext());
        }

        return results;
    }
```

**adapter code (3 of them has similar adapter, so i include one of them)**

```
public class BillListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Bill> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public BillListAdapter(Context aContext, ArrayList<Bill> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(aContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_bill_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            //holder.txtBillNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillId);
            holder.txtBillNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillNo);
            holder.txtBillType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillType);
            holder.txtBillTable = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillTable);
            holder.txtBillQty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillQty);
            holder.txtBillAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillAmount);
            holder.txtBillStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillStatus);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //holder.txtBillId.setText(listData.get(position).getID() +"");
        holder.txtBillNo.setText(listData.get(position).get_bill_no());
        holder.txtBillType.setText(listData.get(position).get_type());
        holder.txtBillTable.setText(listData.get(position).get_table());
        //holder.txtBillQty.setText(listData.get(position).get_qty());
        holder.txtBillAmount.setText(listData.get(position).get_amount());
        holder.txtBillStatus.setText(listData.get(position).get_status());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        //TextView txtBillId;
        TextView txtBillNo;
        TextView txtBillType;
        TextView txtBillTable;
        TextView txtBillQty;
        TextView txtBillAmount;
        TextView txtBillStatus;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to set onClickListener on your gridview item do this.

(I assume you already have the adapter for the gridview). Within the adapter, on 'onBindViewHolder'(if you are using Recyclerview.Adapter) or in 'getView' (if you are using base adaptar) add the click listener on your item. like this ->

```
holder.yourItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do your work on click here
        }
    });
```

hope that helps . :)

Comment: im using gridview by the way, cant we use setOnItemClickListener instead? if we define click on the getView, how can get the id from other listview? which i need pass id from clicking item on listview

Answer (score 1):

We can use multiple GridView and ListView in same Activity.

If you are using clickable(like Button or anything) item as row item in GridView Adapter, that could be the reason your are not getting onItemClick called.

set your button clickable false and then try for the GridView onItemClick

This is common issue for ListView and GridView, if you have used any clickable control as a row item then your onItemClick will not be performed.

**OR**

Apply below attribute in your root layout in which GridView/ListView declared in layout xml

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Also apply below to your clickable control in row xml if any

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42086274/1567907).