# How create ripple programmatically with instead of used xml?

Tags: android, ripple

I can create ripple effect with xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple android:color="#00ff00"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
</ripple>
```

How can I reach the same programmatically with RippleDrawable(...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Ripple effect on a LinearLayout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732662/how-to-set-ripple-effect-on-a-linearlayout-programmatically)

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I want to know how to create this ripple programmatically with RippleDrawable. I will set this RippleDrawable then to background of view.

Comment: then you question should be "how to create this ripple programmatically with RippleDrawable"